# How to write bootloader for multi cores ARM cortex-M0 processor

Tags: arm, bootloader, processor

The cores are categorized into one IO-control core, one
DSP core and two normal cores. I managed to find SWD pins but I'm not sure what software to boot, or do I have to create assembly codes? One thing for sure is I have to know the allocation of memory location, but most likely it starts with 000x000 right?

I used ARM processor as my development board. Similar to the function of an Arduino, just that it has 4 cores.

Comment: have you written code to boot a single core mcu?   how is this different?  you have some other cores that most likely you simply run later (might not even be a bootloader thing, but instead part of the firmware).

Comment: hardware design matters here, looking at the raspberry pi (not an mcu but...) they all release at the same time and you have to "sort the cores"  have a single set of instructions that extracts the core number then either you have a core number based jump table to have each core run its own code or like the pi (or early pi) use the core number to determine a mailbox address and sit in an infinite loop until the mailbox is written with an address to jump to.

Comment: other, more ideal, designs you have control over the individual core resets, and possibly vector mapping, etc.  clearly you need to get the primary core booted just like any other single core.  then either bootloader or probably firmware provides a boot path for each core in turn and releases them but since this is chip company and not arm that determines how this works, you have to look at the chip vendor specific details.

Comment: Highly unlikely that you want to boot all cores at once. You would be creating  synchronization problems that can easily be avoided by starting/booting just one core. Then load more sophisticated software that can start-up & manage the other cores.